# How can we use repeatIn with number? in openerp

Tags: report, odoo

can any one tell me how to use repeatIn to do this

[[repeatIn(o.order_line, 'o') ]]

```
    <blockTable colWidths="20.0,100.0,150.0,80.0,50.0,20.0,60.0,50.0" style="Table_Order_Pur_line_Content_blank">
    <tr> 
         <td> <para style="terp_default_8"><font color="white"> </font></para></td>
         <td> <para style="terp_default_8"><font color="white"> </font></para></td>
         <td> <para style="terp_default_8"><font color="white"> </font></para></td>
         <td> <para style="terp_default_8"><font color="white"> </font></para></td>
         <td> <para style="terp_default_8"><font color="white"> </font></para></td>
         <td> <para style="terp_default_8"><font color="white"> </font></para></td>
         <td> <para style="terp_default_8"><font color="white"> </font></para></td>
         <td> <para style="terp_default_8"><font color="white"> </font></para></td>
    </tr>
      </blockTable> -->
```

I want to add blank rows multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing a list of dictionary, for example [{'a':1},{'a':2},{'a':1}...] as an argument to repeatLn(), then you will be able to do this. If you know how much lines you want then for example `repeatLn([{'a':i} for i in range(10)],'l')` or `repeatLn([map(lambda x:{'a':x},range(10)),'l')`

Comment: The number of lines i want to take is dynamic. and how can i count lines of any table??

Comment: You have to think over it.because number of lines depends on the length of the string. If the description or data in a column is big then it automatically comes to next line.

Answer (score 0):

I use repeatIn function with another function for dynamic input. and it seems working fine.